# Looking for a way to call a Javascript function when a mouse event occurs for any path in an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick

I have an SVG with thousands of paths in this format:

```
<path id="c02130" d="m256.29 573.18-0.78515 1.1758h1.1777v-0.78516zm0.39258-1...
  <title>Ketchikan Gateway, AK</title>
</path>
```

I need to call a Javascript function whenever a mouse event occurs for the path. Currently, I do this on click and it works well:

```
<path id="c02130" onclick="on('c021830')"  d="m256.29 573.18-0.78515 1.1758h1.1777v-...
  <title>Ketchikan Gateway, AK</title>
</path>
```

The on() function fetches text from the server using AJAX and writes it to a <div> area.

I'm wondering if there's a better way that doesn't require adding an onclick to each path, given that all paths will be treated the same way - passing their id to a Javascript function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

add the onClick event listener, to the svg, and use the `event.target` to see where is the event comes from something like this:

```
<script>
function onSvg(event) {
  on(event.target.id);
}
</script>
<svg onClick="onSvg" ></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That worked well once I realized it had to be onClick="onSvg(event)"
I'm a novice at event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Try and avoid inline events, the more modern way is to use `addEventListener`.

Note: because events bubble, you don't need to add the event to every element, add to the parent and do some basic checking there.

eg. Below I've created two Rect's with ID's, I then check to make sure what was click was a Rect, and then console.log the ID.

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'rect')
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="red" width="20" height="20" fill="red"/>
  <rect id="blue" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" x="20" y="20" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There is no reason to avoid _inline_ events, unless you need multiple listeners on one element.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman  I think you kind of answered you own comment.  How do you know there are not going to be more listeners.  Let's say this OP created this into a component for use with others,.  Now the consumer decided he wanted to also attach to the click event of the `svg`.  There are other reasons, but I'll let MDN clarify here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these

Comment: You added to answer, only when you **want** 3rd parties to add listeners, you need to use ``addEventListener``. In Web Component development the developer is in control and in 99 of a 100 cases _inline_ Events are all that is needed, **and** easier (and with less code) to set. Using ``Object.assign`` is the game changer

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman  I really don't want to argue with you, but did you even look at the MDN link.  I mean even this -> `Finally, many common server configurations will disallow inline JavaScript, as a security measure.` should really be of concern.  But instead of trying to convince me, maybe your time would be best spent getting MDN to change there website -> `You should never use the HTML event handler attributes — those are outdated, and using them is bad practice.`

Comment: You quote "server configurations". **Client side** will forever allow any type of the **three** Event technologies we can use; Backwards compatibility is what the Internet is all about. I can still run the webpages I built in 1994 I have given up on changing faulty MDN documentation, it usually ends up in a fierce debate with youngsters who have been doing this business for a life-time... they're 30-something

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman  I think you miss the point of "server configurations", some servers will strip the `inline` events, it's not even going to get to the client.  But if your happy writing code that might not work on certain servers, then that's fine, if your hosting your own, fair enough.  But using them is bad practice, and the reasons are plain to see and explained in detail.  You are of course totally fine ignoring what MDN says, nobody is forcing you to use `addEventListener`, but I will continue to advice people not to use `inline` events regardless.

Comment: And eval is evil

Answer (score 0):

If your "on" function is the same for any svg in the system, i.e., doesn't depend on context, you could setup a universal listener. If it's context specific, then follow Peter's advice.

```
function setupSvgListeners(){
  document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    on(event.target.id);
  }
}
```